# update mongodb atlas database schema

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

When I create a collection and add a model like below, is there I way that I can change through the cli? or add one after a collection is created?

problem: how to update the data model/how to add a model after creation

I tried with db.students.update, but does not work.

```
db.createCollection("students", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
          bsonType: "object",
          required: [ "name", "year", "major", "gpa", "address.city", "address.street" ],        
                    }
               }
     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a **database** schema. It's **validation** schema. Please learn the difference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/index.html.

Among other important info on the page the following sentences answer your questions precisely:

> Validation occurs during updates and inserts. When you add validation to a collection, existing documents do not undergo validation checks until modification.

You will need to process existing documents yourself to ensure they comply.

> To add document validation to an existing collection, use collMod command with the validator option.

It equally applies to update of existing validation rules. In your case the command should be something like this:

```
db.runCommand({ collMod: "students", "validator": {"$jsonSchema" : <your new schema> } })
```